# Factor of a Graph

Tags: graph-theory

Is $K_{2n}$ $2$-factorable? Illustrate with an example.

$K_4$ is $2$-factorable but at many places it is generalized that $K_{2n}$ is not $2$-factorable. Is saying that a $2$-factor exists in a graph the same as saying the graph is $2$-factorable?

Answer (score 2):

Let's remember the definitions. A *$2$-factor* of a graph $G$ is a spanning $2$-regular subgraph. In other words, a $2$-factor consists of a set of subgraphs of $G$, where each subgraph in the set is a (non-trivial) cycle, and where every vertex is on exactly one cycle. A *$2$-factorization* is a set of $2$-factors with the property that every edge in the graph is in exactly one $2$-factor. A graph is *$2$-factorable* if it has a $2$-factorization.

This is somewhat analogous to the prime factorization of an integer $n$. A single prime dividing $n$ is a prime factor, while the prime factorization of $n$ is the expression of $n$ as a product of prime factors.

Now as opposed to integers, not every graph has a $2$-factorization. In fact, notice that if a graph does have a $2$-factorization, then every vertex must have even degree. This is because each $2$-factor in the $2$-factorization contributes exactly two to the degree of every vertex, and every edge is in exactly one $2$-factor.